# "laravel" command on Homestead 2 doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am running homestead 2.0, and when I run `laravel new` command, it throws an error.

```
vagrant@homestead:/home/Code$ laravel new lproject
laravel: command not found
```

I did install laravel globally:

```
vagrant@homestead:/home/Code$ composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to /home/vagrant/.config/composer
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Using version ^1.3 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/installer (v1.3.4)
  - Installing laravel/installer (v1.3.5)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

My path already includes ~/.composer/vendor/bin.

```
vagrant@homestead:/home/Code$ echo $PATH
∼/.composer/vendor/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/root/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Still laravel command fails.

```
vagrant@homestead:/home/Code$ laravel
-bash: /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try a fresh shell? `exec bash`

Comment: Ran exec bash. Still nothing.

Comment: Not sure, but I'd probably just run a fresh install of the virtual machine...

Comment: @upful . Lot of work.

Comment: it only took 3 minutes to download a copy `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` ... https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two ... but also I did notice that the `laravel` command is already installed globally

Comment: @upful, Internet speed depends on where in the world is the user. :). I will wait till i can't manage any more with the box, till I reset homestead. 

Also, reinstalling shouldn't be a solution for a problem like this.